# Unable to invoke Rally LBAPI WS from ruby rest-client program. Any

Tags: ruby, rally, rest-client

I have been able to query rally analytics API using DHC(Dev HTTP Client) with the following POST request 
http://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/1234/artifact/snapshot/query.js&API_Key=key123
and body
{
   "find": {
       "ObjectID": 4321
    }
}

Is there any way I can do this from Ruby? I have using 'rest-client' but am only getting errors endlessly (400, 403, ....) 
Has anyone been able to do this ? 
Is this possible using curl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using both curl and ruby. You need to set a ZSESSIONID header value equal to your API Key. Curl example here (randomized Workspace OID and API Key):

```
curl -X POST \
'https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/v2.0/service/rally/workspace/12345678910/artifact/snapshot/query' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'ZSESSIONID: _m31qjdm43Ou74h0cACk28zgBUOPm50Xtna2PhQ2L22' \
--data '{"find":{"FormattedID": "DE9", "__At": "current"},"fields":true,"start":0,"pagesize":10,"removeUnauthorizedSnapshots":true}' \
--compressed
```

It is fairly straightforward to do in Ruby also. The following Gists:

- [Rally Lookback Connection Helper](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c30bf9f99c2fb2c45b27)
- [Rally Lookback Query Example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f456e6a51312023393b4)

Contain a Ruby connection helper for connecting to Rally's Lookback API. The second Gist contains an example of using the connection helper along with a hash representing a find query object. The Ruby example uses `httpclient` gem as opposed to `rest-client` gem, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Many thanks. I am able to connect and get a response. However the result list is empty. Also the client I had to change the following "FormattedID": "DE9" to "FormattedID"=> "DE9". I do not have curl on my system. I think it will work.

Comment: Good catch on the `=>`. I accidentally switched to JSON in the middle. Interestingly, ruby 2.2.1, which I'm running, will accept either the `=>` or the  `:` in a hash definition. Anyway, I've updated the Gist so that it works in general.

Comment: I use ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25) [i386-mingw32], when i changed from api_key to username/credential (to check the behaviour as i am not getting any results) I get the following error: <Path to>/rally_lookback_connection_helper.rb:38:in `set_client_auth':
 undefined local variable or method `config' for #<RallyLookbackConnectionHelper:0x2eacbe0> (NameError)
        from <path to>/rally_lookback_connection_helper.rb:31:in `initialize'
        from rally_lookback_query.rb:12:in `new'
        from rally_lookback_query.rb:12:in `<main>'

Comment: Oops, sorry about that - the set_client_auth method had a typo. Fixed in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c30bf9f99c2fb2c45b27, and re-linked to new Gist in the edited answer.

Comment: In terms of not getting results - have you tried different formatted ID's/ different artifacts? DE9 is just an example defect I'm polling in my environment, so you may need to substitute a Formatted ID of an Artifact (Story, Defect, etc.) that you know exists and is not recycled, in the Rally Workspace that is of interest to you. Formatted ID's are workspace-specific, so make sure that the Formatted ID is present in the Workspace whose Object ID you're using to query.

Comment: The problem was i had given the ObjectId as "ObjectId"=> "14321". I retried after removing the "" and go the expected results. Many Many thanks to you for the utility!!

Answer (score 0):

Has this API changed ? We had a change in our username recently and since then, running the Query example returns {"_rallyAPIMajor":"2","_rallyAPIMinor":"0","Errors":["Not Found"],"Warnings":[]}
for all the queries.